# origin-pod not starting with fresh 3.6 install

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

I am setting up two Openshift Origins clusters running on RHEL 7.4.

The only thing that really shows me anything that is really wrong is this error log from the origin-pod from the docker node.

```
error: --deployment or OPENSHIFT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME is required
```

This leads me to think the deployment name is not getting passed to the container at startup.  It then crashes not letting the deploy spin up.  I see a ton of CNI errors but this is due to all containers assigned to this pod are killed as the origin-pod fails.

Here are the version of everything I could thing of that is needed to help find the true problem.

```
oc v3.6.0+c4dd4cf
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://is-origins-tetration.cisco.com:8443
openshift v3.6.0+c4dd4cf
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7


docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-55.gitc4618fb.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      c4618fb/1.12.6
 Built:           Thu Aug 24 14:48:49 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-55.gitc4618fb.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      c4618fb/1.12.6
 Built:           Thu Aug 24 14:48:49 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

oci-umount-1.12.6-55.gitc4618fb.el7.x86_64
oci-register-machine-0-3.11.1.gitdd0daef.el7.x86_64
oci-systemd-hook-0.1.12-1.git1e84754.el7.x86_64
```

Has anyone else seen this type of error?

Comment: For issues with setting up an OpenShift cluster, better to ask on one of the lists at https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo